# Twilio SMS Status check by API (Without webhook)

Tags: twilio

Is there any  API to retrieve the status of the SMS message based on SID (SMS ID) without using web hook? So, we can call API whenever we need to find the status of the SID. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Twilio's [SMS API Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api#send-messages-with-the-sms-api), you post and fetch SMS messages using the `Message` resource.

Here's the API format:

```
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages/{Sid}.json
```

References:

- [Fetch a Message Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#fetch-a-message-resource) API docs
- [Credentials](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/requests-to-twilio#credentials): Auth Tokens and API keys
- [Message Properties](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#message-properties) including `status`.
- [Message Status Values](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#message-status-values)